# How to show the spacy output in tkinter textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, spacy

I want to show the spacy output in my second textbox from tkinter, however I just manage to read the text file that i want to tokenize, I need to read the spacy output with the text file already tokenized, this is how it's my code to show the pre-tokenize text, how can i get the spacy output in the textbox?

```
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
doc = nlp(open('rainbow.txt').read())
for token in doc:
    print(token.text,",")

def tokenize():
    stuff2 = doc=nlp(open('rainbow.txt').read())

    my_text2.insert(END, stuff2)
    text_file.close()


open_button2 = Button(root, text="Compilar", command=tokenize)
open_button2.place(x=5,y=5)

root.mainloop()
```

I need to get the

```
print(token.text,",")
```

output for the button 2

I need to get the print token output for the textbox 2

Answer (score 0):

This standalone code should work for what you are trying to do. You might have to change a *few* things back because I dont have spacy not do I know how to use it, and I dont have the same files that you have.

```
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
doc = nlp(open('rainbow.txt').read())
for token in doc:
    print(token.text,",")

def tokenize():
    stuff2 = token.text, ","

    my_text2.insert(END, stuff2)



open_button2 = Button(root, text="Compilar", command=tokenize)
open_button2.place(x=5,y=5)

root.mainloop()
```

You can run this code and see why/how it works and work off of that.

Comment: I tried with the code you gave me, however it showed the "rainbow.txt" as a label, and the output i needed wasn't the one that print(token.text) is giving me, it just gives me the original text file again

Comment: you can add the rainbowtext.txt part back in, here is the exact code you wrote originally with the small changes I made.

Comment: (Ill edit my post)

Comment: thanks so much, that's what I did on the answer i wrote, however i'm just getting a single word from the token.text, I need to get them all, I will show you in a edit of my answer..

Comment: most likely the texts are getting put ontop of eachother. change .pack() to `.place(x=40, y=25*c)` and have a `c=1` that increments every time the loop runs. that should work if the reason is what i said prior.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem I already have .place for both text box and the first one is a box that reads a file I open, does it without a problem, but the second one that reads the token.text, just shows one item from the text :(

Comment: oof. I wish i could help further but im out of ideas.

Comment: thank you for your help, i'll try to get it fixed :(

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to display in `textbox2`. Add parameters to the `tokenize` function. Then called `tokenize`.

code:

```
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
doc = nlp(open('rainbow.txt').read())

for token in doc:
    print(token.text,",")
stuff2 = token.text, ","    

def tokenize(data):     
    my_text2.insert(END, data)

open_button2 = Button(root, text="Compilar", command=tokenize)
open_button2.place(x=5,y=5)

tokenize(stuff2)

root.mainloop()
```